# Automate iPhone Setting/Facebook app using UI Automation

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I have refereed the below forum for automating iPhone Settings using UI Automation tool. It's showing "iOS Simulator failed to install the application." error when started recording:

[Automation of Settings app, iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541251/ui-automation-of-settings-iphone)

Could you please share how to automate iPhone Settings using UI Automation tool? Could you please share also how to automate third party app like Facebook or Twitter using UI Automation tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the Settings app on the device itself, you cannot use UI Automation to automate any interactions with it. However, there's a way to access the Settings app on the simulator. See my response on the posting you've linked.

As for automating the Facebook or Twitter apps, UI Automation can only be used with applications in which you have access to the source code.

Comment: Ricordo ,I have tried your solution before asking this question but i got the error message when i started to record the with Preferences.app in  Xcode , the error message is : "iOS Simulator failed to install the application. , what is your solution to solve this issue and automate phone setting please?